# Contact form 7 recaptcha validation

Tags: php, json, wordpress, recaptcha

I have a problem with contact form 7 recaptcha validation. From what I saw I get these as json response:

[image: json error]

These is the code I use for recaptcha in contact form 7: [recaptcha theme:dark]

And I had set up the integration config: Site Key and Secret Key.

Comment: Looks like a conflict with another (possibly poorly written) plugin, or a bug. You're unlikely to find any help here unless someone else has experienced the exact same issue.

Comment: The general approach for checking conflicts is to first disable all other plugins except the one that appears not to work; this includes themes that have plugins built in or plugin-like functionality. If unsure, temporarily switch to a default theme provided by WordPress. If the problem is still there, it's caused by either the configuration of the plugin or if a bug, so take it up with the official support for it. If the problem is gone, gradually re-enable other plugins, starting first with your disabled theme, then the remaining plugins by halves.

Comment: I just turned that plugin off and installed another one. Now it works fine :D